# artifactory flag artifacts as 'integration' not working so far

Tags: integration, artifactory

I am using artifactory to store my artifacts, using a generic repo (I named it 'generic-local') and a layout that I have customized based on the maven2 layout (I believe one of the default layouts)

unchanged layout 
[orgPath]/[module]/baseRev/[module]-baseRev(-[classifier]).[ext]

my version are of the following format

- myartifact-1.0.0
- myartifact-1.0.0-develop
- myartifact-1.0.0-branch1234

to detect and flag release artifact.. I understand artifactory relies on certain regex

the Folder Integration Revision RegExp and File Integration Revision RegExp

for both I have set this regexp to 'branch.*|develop.*'

I would expect artifactory to now flag as 'integration' any artifact following the two last artifacts in my list above but it isn't working so far..

http://myrepo.com/artifactory/api/search/versions?g=My.Applications&a=myartifact&repos=generic-local

```
returns
{
  "results": [
    {
      "version": "1.0.267-branch1234",
      "integration": false
    },
    {
      "version": "1.0.266-branch1234",
      "integration": false
    },
    {
      "version": "1.0.265-branch1234",
      "integration": false
    }
}
```

I tested the Test Artifact Path Resolution form in artifactory .. for each artifacts above, it returned :

Folder Integration Revision: branch1234
File Integration Revision: branch1234

Which makes me think my regex is valid. thus the artifacts are seen as integration .. however the api returns false.. 
What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is working. I can see artifacts finally flagged with the flag integration=true. 
I can use this to, for example, run 'deploy latest stable version'.

The fix was to wait. Seems artifactory does not apply the rule right away. even for new artifacts added after the rule change. Confusing and wished their documentation would mentioned it.